# phpinfo() shows nothing but all my other php scripts work fine

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, php

On my LAMP stack I just did a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in Ubuntu. Then I went to one of my localhost sites and it loaded up fine and functions correctly.

Then I needed to view some info on the PHP info page so I created phpinfo.php with

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` inside, went to the page in Chromium browser and nothing. I get a blank page. I checked the Apache2 error.log but there were no errors.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Search the following line in your php.ini file:

```
disable_functions = phpinfo
```

and change it to

```
disable_functions =
```

(I think that commenting it will work as well)